# How do I bind a hazelcast node to a specific ip address?

Tags: java, scala, hazelcast, vert.x

I tried running this code, but it gives me an error. It seems that I can't bind to a specific ip address; rather I need to bind to a network interface. is there any way around this issue?

```
import io.vertx.core.VertxOptions
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx
import io.vertx.spi.cluster.hazelcast.{ ConfigUtil, HazelcastClusterManager }

object Test extends App {
  val host = "127.0.0.2"
  def getConfig(): Config = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    val config = ConfigUtil.loadConfig()
    config.setProperty("hazelcast.socket.bind.any", "false")
    config
      .getNetworkConfig
      .setPortAutoIncrement(false)
      .getInterfaces
      .setEnabled(true)
      .setInterfaces(List(s"127.0.0.2").asJava)
    val joinConfig = config.getNetworkConfig.getJoin

    joinConfig
      .getMulticastConfig
      .setEnabled(false)

    config
  }
  def run(): Unit = {
    val mgr = new HazelcastClusterManager(getConfig())
    val options = new VertxOptions().setClusterManager(mgr)
    options.getEventBusOptions.setHost(host)
    val vrtx = Vertx.rxClusteredVertx(options).blockingGet()
  }
  run()
}
```

I'm getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Hazelcast CANNOT start on this node. No matching network interface found.`

Comment: I needed to add the ip address to the loopback interface. look https://askubuntu.com/questions/444124/how-to-add-a-loopback-interface for details.

Answer (score 0):

Check this section of the documentation & the link in the doc: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#discovering-members-by-tcp

What you need is to disable Hazelcast to bind all interfaces by setting `hazelcast.socket.bind.any` to `false`. Then, you can use the Interfaces as described in here: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#interfaces